# Top N values basing on various criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple table of characters, their gender and stats.

| Character | Gender | Strength | Constitution | Agility |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | F | 15 | 10 | 7 |
| Bob | M | 10 | 15 | 8 |
| Charlie | F | 8 | 14 | 5 |
| Dylan | M | 9 | 9 | 17 |

I wanted to make a Best 3 table basing on some criteria, eg.

Best 3, Strength:

| No. | All | Female | Male |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Alice | Bob |
| 2 | Bob | Charlie | Dylan |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... |

To get the strongest among all people I simply use:

```
=LARGE(C2:C5;1)
```

To get the strongest among females I know I need something like:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS({B2:B5};"F");LARGE(C2:C5;1))
```

Where `{B2:B5}` is a range of the "Gender" column, `C2:C5` is a range for "Strength" column. But this gives me the value from the "Strength" column (15), and I need a corresponding value from the "Character" column (Alice). I don't know how to nest another function that will give me the corresponding name.

I would also be grateful if the function would give **all** the names that match the criterion, eg. if there was Elliot with strength 15, his name should be displayed along with Alice. But I have no clue how to ever approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top 3 'All' try

```
=query(A2:E5, "Select A where B <>'' order by C desc limit 3", 0)
```

and you can use the same logic for the top 3 'Male'

```
=query(A2:E5, "Select A where B = 'M' order by C desc limit 3", 0)
```

and 'Female'

```
=query(A2:E5, "Select A where B = 'F' order by C desc limit 3", 0)
```

See if that works for you?

---

### Reference

- [Query()](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/)